# How do I write a table valued function in Teradata?

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions, teradata

So, I'm trying to write a table valued function in Teradata with a SQL function, but I'm having a hard time figuring out the syntax, or if it's even possible. I've gotten a scalar value function to work, and I've seen examples of table-valued function is C-UDFs, but not any for SQL-UDFs.

```
REPLACE FUNCTION APP.STAMPLE (
    "a" INTEGER,
    "b" INTEGER)
    RETURNS TABLE
    VARYING COLUMNS(2)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    CONTAINS SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COLLATION INVOKER
    RETURN SELECT (A + B as val, 'A' as funct)
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL-UDFs are limited to simple scalar functions in Teradata, i.e. no SELECTs, etc.
If you need a more complex function (table or [window] aggregate) you must write it in C or Java.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. The documentation that I saw didn't mention anything like that, but it also didn't have table valued examples.